# Async nature of Angular Protractor tests with waits

Tags: angular, selenium, asynchronous, protractor, wait

I have the following typescript class I use for protractor tests.  An OpenAM server is running for the auth.

```
import { element, by, ElementFinder, browser, ExpectedConditions} from 'protractor';
import { BasePage } from './base.pageobject';
import { SelectSitePage } from './select-site.pageobject';

export class AuthPage extends BasePage {
    readonly url: string = '/';

    readonly loginMenu: ElementFinder = element(by.css('nav.profile-menu'));
    readonly loginLink: ElementFinder = element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Login'));
    readonly logoutLink: ElementFinder = element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Logout'));

    // On OpenAM login page
    readonly userNameField: ElementFinder = element(by.id('idToken1'));
    readonly passwordField: ElementFinder = element(by.id('idToken2'));
    readonly loginButton: ElementFinder = element(by.id('loginButton_0'));
    readonly aintExist: ElementFinder = element(by.id('loginButton_666'));

    private selectSitePage: SelectSitePage = new SelectSitePage();

    /**
     * Log in if are not already
     */
    public logIn() {
        this.loginMenu.click();
        this.loginLink.isPresent().then((isPresent: boolean) => {
            if (isPresent) {
                this.loginLink.click();

                this.disableWaitingForAngular();
                var EC = ExpectedConditions;
                let loginButtonExpected = EC.presenceOf(this.loginButton);
                console.log('wait for login button ...');
                browser.driver.wait(loginButtonExpected, 2000);
                console.log('login button present');
                this.userNameField.clear();
                this.userNameField.sendKeys('user');
                this.passwordField.clear();
                this.passwordField.sendKeys('pw');
                this.loginButton.click();

                let searchBoxExpected = EC.presenceOf(this.selectSitePage.searchBox);
                console.log('wait for searchBox ...');
                browser.driver.wait(searchBoxExpected, 2000);
                console.log('searchBox present');

                this.enableWaitingForAngular();
            } else {
                console.log('AuthPage / logIn - already logged in');
            }
        });
    }
```

This runs fine, however the `console.log`s come out almost immediately as if the `wait()`s have no effect on them.  However the test fails if removed so it seems they are relevant.

Is it that the waits are only for WebDriver objects?  The doco doesn't make this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all commands in Protractor are `async`. This means that they first needs to be resolved. This also counts for the `wait`, see the [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait).

So in your case the commands are all executed after each other, but because the `console.log()` is sync it will log a result sooner than the promis of the previous line has been resolved.

Maybe [this article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/02/16/how-javascript-promises-work/) can help you with promises if you are having troubles with them.

If you want the `console.log()` to take place after the previous line you can do something like this

```
var EC = ExpectedConditions;
let loginButtonExpected = EC.presenceOf(this.loginButton);
console.log('wait for login button ...');
browser.driver.wait(loginButtonExpected, 2000)
    .then(() => {
       console.log('login button present');
    });
```

By the way. You are using TypeScript. That means that you can also use the methods `async / await`, that will make your code more "sync" and the `await` will "hold" executing the next line before the previous line has been resolved. See also an example project on [protractor github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/exampleTypescript)

Hope it helps

Comment: Ok yeah, that makes sense.  I'm ok with Promises but to realise that **Almost all commands in protractory are `async`** is the key.  Now if they are all async then what stops them resolving out of order?  Thanks for the tip about `async` and `await`.  Given that protractor seems to roll its own Promises I didn't think that would work.  Thanks!

Comment: That's were the Control flow is for, see [here](protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md)

Comment: Yes I remembered reading that I read about that.  And thus why Protractor has its own Promises as they operate in special execution contexts outside of core / native promises.  Choice!  BTW the link is https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md

Comment: Tnx, and that is I a see it also the reason why they are going to remove it

Comment: Is that because the different Promise is confusing?  It makes sense so it will be interesting to see what they come up with.